# Check if one or more directory exists- Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to print the line for each directory, if the directory/file does not exist i need to display "missing".

```
file="file.txt"
if [[ -d "$/folders/folder1" && -d "$/folders/folder1" ...]]; then
  if [ -e "$file" ]; then
      #the files that exist and contain the file, call the function
      for i in folder{1..11}; do
          echo  $i function
      done
   else
       #for the directories that don't exist
       echo "no directory exists"
 fi

else
   #for the directories that don't exist
   echo "no directory exists"
```

Comment: you know about `for i in folder{1..1}}`, why not run a separate loop first to see that all the folders are there? As is, we can't tell what you mean (or what you have in your actual script), when you write `if [[ -d "$/folders/folder1" && -d "$/folders/folder1" ...]]; then` . Did you check your code at https://shellcheck.net ? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your requirements from the comments, you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

do_stuff() {
    local file=$1
    local score max junk
    IFS=$'/ \t' read -r score max junk < <(tail -n 1 "$file")
    echo "$score / $max"
}

file="feedback.txt"

for dir in folders/folder{1..11}; do
    if ! [[ -f "$dir/$file" ]]; then
        echo "${dir##*/}: missing"
        continue
    fi

    #OK - do stuff here
    do_stuff "$dir/$file"
done
```

Comment: Pluse-uno for tech support (and as always, a very good answer). Good luck to all.